# Sort an array of numbers into ascending order and find the position of a number within the list

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have produced an unsorted array of values of which I would like to put into an ascending order and determine the new position of the last number.

I have previously attempted successfully at other smaller input but got stuck on the last one where the the list consists of 1824300 values and the terminal just wouldn't run the sorting algorithm at all...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  signed value = 16239, num = 1824300, i, j;
  signed temp;
  signed arr[num];

  arr[0] = value;
  printf("Your initial array is:\n");
  printf("%i\n", arr[0]);

  for (i = 1; i < num; i++)
  {
   value = (value*31334)%31337;
   arr[i]= value;
   printf("%i:  ", i);
   printf("%i\n", arr[i]);
  }

// Insertion sort
 for(i = 1; i < num; i++)
 {
  j = i;
  temp = arr[j];

  while((j > 0) && (arr[j - 1] > temp))
    {
      arr[j] = arr[j -1];
      arr[j - 1] = temp;
      j--;
    }
}
insertion sort //

printf("Your sorted array is:\n");

for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
  printf("%i:  ", i);
  printf("%i\n", arr[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help me on it?
P.S. I am completely new to programming so my code might be very inefficient and messy so sorry about that!!
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Insertion sort in the worst case is an `O(n^2)` algorithm.  With nearly 2 million entries, perhaps you've exhausted the resources of your system.

Comment: You should take a look  at more efficient sorting algorithms. Insertion sort runs at O(n^2) meaning that for a input array of size n it requires n^2 comparasions. A much better algorithm would for instance be quick sort witch runs in O(n log n)

Comment: Merge sort is conceptually pretty straightforward, and much more efficient than what you're doing here. With 2M entries, the recursion depth would be in the twenties, certainly not problematic. However you end up sorting, once done, search for the element however you like: even linear search is better than the fastest comparison-based sorting method. Of course, with a sorted list, you could binary search if you wanted to, but why bother.

Comment: Or, you could just call the built-in `qsort` function. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm

Comment: *How* does the sort "get stuck"?  Is it stopped, waiting for memory?  Is it too slow?  You can trace the progress with one or two strategically-placed `print` statements.  Also, more efficient sorting algorithms are easy to search on line.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

So basically below is what I did at the end. I just inserted a simple counter! and it worked fine... Thank you for everyone who tried to help. Your answers are valuable to me and I am still learning how to implement the algorithms into codes which is a bit difficult for me since I have no programming experience before :((( The algorithms are not tricky to understand at all though...

```
signed count;
count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
  if (arr[i] <= value)
  {
  count = count + 1;
  }
}
printf("This is the index of your output in a sorted list: \n");
printf("%i\n", count);
```